# Singular or plural when indicating something unique owned by many

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, singular-vs-plural, generic-noun-phrases

In the following sentences, which one is correct?

- Tom likes dogs with long tails.
- Tom likes dogs with **a** long tail.

There are many tails because there are many dogs. But each dog has only one tail. I prefer the second sentence, but I am not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, there's also an idiomatic form for expressing preference: "Tom likes **a** dog with **a** long tail." Taken literally, it refers to a specific dog. It can be used, however, to describe Tom's taste in dog tails in general.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both sentences are correct and understandable.

To this native speaker, the first sounds more native-spoken, even though there may be interpreted as **many dogs each having multiple tails**.

The second is more wordy and does not sound natural since we already know that dogs only have **one** tail.  However, if the speaker further describes the tail then **a** would be used :

> Tom likes dogs with **a full, bushy tail**.

Comment: Your second point also indicates why not using "a" is acceptable in the first sentence -- because the multiple long tails are not multiple tails on a single dog, they are multiple *types* of long tails. `Tom likes dogs with long tails`, maybe they are bushy tails, maybe skinny, maybe it has a tuft of fur on the end, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I don't even know whether there's a rule here. For what it's worth:

**Your first sentence is correct.** The second one sounds kind of lame.

That said, there may be exceptions, such as when the plural form doesn't make sense while the singular does. As in:

**I happen to like people with a good eye for architecture.**

Answer (score 4):

This is correct:

> 1. Tom likes dogs with long tails.

This one is also correct:

> 2. Tom likes dogs with a long tail.

Refer to this book on Google Books.<sup>1</sup>

Here is an excerpt:

> [image]

---

Have a good look at this chart from Google Books Ngram Viewer too:

> [image]

<sub>1. [Current Issues in Romance Languages](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=a_SZjq2GUYsC&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=%22dogs+with+a+long+tail%22&source=bl&ots=H8LW2b2HyA&sig=lRjAXhL4cRlTUmMq-8QZitjh9Es&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1kLCxwNvJAhVBBY4KHajeCkoQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22dogs%20with%20a%20long%20tail%22&f=false)</sub>